# Python Graphing data from input file

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib

I need to take weather data from a previous assignment and make various graphs. The dataset I'm having the most trouble with is descriptions. All I have so far is the data file. I know I need to run a for loop to read it and make the data graphable. So far all I've done is read in the file.

`descriptions = open('descriptions.txt', 'r',encoding=('utf-8'))`

The data looks like this. What I need to do eventually is make a bar graph that counts the instances of certain keywords (such as rainy or showers as rain. Sunny/Clear as Sun. Etc.). How exactly would I run the loop so that the days are associated with the right city? And then how would I associate the word counts with the right day?

> Cleveland Data
> Sunday Cleveland
> Showers Likely and Patchy Fog, Heavy Rain and Patchy Fog then Slight Chance Showers, Sunny and Breezy, Clear, Sunny, Increasing Clouds
> Monday Cleveland
> Clear, Sunny, Mostly Clear, Chance Showers then Showers, Showers, Chance Showers then Partly Sunny and Breezy
> Tuesday Cleveland
> Sunny, Increasing Clouds, Slight Chance Showers then Rain, Rain, Showers Likely, Partly Cloudy and Blustery

> Detroit Data
> Sunday Detroit
> Slight Chance Showers, Gradual Clearing, Sunny, Clear, Sunny, Mostly Cloudy then Showers Likely
> Monday Detroit
> Clear, Sunny, Partly Cloudy then Showers Likely, Showers, Chance Showers then Chance Rain/Snow, Partly Sunny, Mostly Clear
> Tuesday Detroit
> Chance Showers, Slight Chance Snow Showers then Chance Rain/Snow, Slight Chance Snow Showers then Mostly Clear, Sunny, Clear, Sunny

Comment: well You can compare each word to a list of city names and if it matches the city name all the text after is from that city, and so on

Comment: another way is to split the file data in cities which will depend how data about cities is seperated. for example is the space between information blocks `\n\n`?

Comment: @Matiiss Yes. Right now after the data from the last day of one city is \n\n

Answer (score 0):

ok, so here is my take (explanation in comments; if You have questions, ask them):

```
# opens and reads the whole file
with open('text_file.txt') as file:
    data = file.read()

# splits read data in groups between whom are \n\n and stores them in a list
data = data.split('\n\n')

# creates a dictionary
data_by_city = {}

# this loops over each section in the data list (each city info block)
for item in data:
    # creates a dictionary to store text info
    city_data = {}
    
    # for each city info entry removes all \n
    item = item.replace('\n', ' ')
    # splits each city info by spaces
    split_item = item.split(' ')
    # checks if word is in city_data and if not then adds it if it exists adds up the count
    for word in split_item:
        if word not in city_data.keys():
            city_data[word] = 1
        else:
            city_data[word] += 1
    
    # creates an entry for data_by_city and makes the key name of the city and city_data as the assigned value
    data_by_city[split_item[0] if split_item[0] != '' else split_item[1]] = city_data

# prints data_by_city
print(data_by_city)
```

and this is the input file (lines show boundaries of the file):

> 

Cleveland Data
Sunday Cleveland
Showers Likely and Patchy Fog, Heavy Rain and Patchy Fog then Slight Chance Showers, Sunny and Breezy, Clear, Sunny, Increasing Clouds
Monday Cleveland
Clear, Sunny, Mostly Clear, Chance Showers then Showers, Showers, Chance Showers then Partly Sunny and Breezy
Tuesday Cleveland
Sunny, Increasing Clouds, Slight Chance Showers then Rain, Rain, Showers Likely, Partly Cloudy and Blustery

Detroit Data
Sunday Detroit
Slight Chance Showers, Gradual Clearing, Sunny, Clear, Sunny, Mostly Cloudy then Showers Likely
Monday Detroit
Clear, Sunny, Partly Cloudy then Showers Likely, Showers, Chance Showers then Chance Rain/Snow, Partly Sunny, Mostly Clear
Tuesday Detroit
Chance Showers, Slight Chance Snow Showers then Chance Rain/Snow, Slight Chance Snow Showers then Mostly Clear, Sunny, Clear, Sunny

> 

and there are two spaces between both info blocks and no spaces between the lines and info blocks